# Improve regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to match something like this in PHP:

```
class-11/xxx/xxx/xx/xxx/things_to_remember/
class-12/xxx/xxx/xx/xxx/things_to_remember/
```

However I don't want to match something like this:

```
xxx/class-11/xxx/
class-11/xxx/things_to_remember/xxx
class-11/xxx/
```

I am writing it like this:

```
^(class-[12]{2})/.+/things_to_remember/$
```

I heard regular expression have many features like greedy etc. and they also need to be efficient ? Is the above regualar expression good ?

Comment: Have you tested it on anything? What were the results? Are they what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little regex here that captures it like the format you wrote. It might need some slight changes as I didn't know how many digits could be in after class.

```
/
class-(\d{2}) #Matches class, makes sure that class only is 2 digits - captures class digits
\/([^\/]{3}) #captures first 3 characters that aren't a slash.
\/([^\/]{3}) #Capture 3 characters again.
\/([^\/]{2}) #captures two characters
\/([^\/]{3}) #Captures 3 characters
\/things_to_remember\/ #Matches last piece of string.
/xg
```

You can [test it out here.](https://regex101.com/r/sW6yJ0/1)